# performSelector won't pass object to the selector

Tags: iphone, nsobject

I have an NSSet-object that I want to pass in a `performSelector`-call:

```
NSSet *myNSSetObject = [self getSet];

if (myNSSetObject.count != 1)
    return;

[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:myNSSetObject afterDelay:0.5];
```

Problem is that the Object arrives empty in `myMethod`. As performSelector retains the passed Object I don't understand what's going wrong.

My Method is defined as follows

```
- (void)myMethod:(NSSet *)myNSSetParam {
   NSLog(@"Set count: %d", myNSSetParam.count);
   [do sth];
}
```

The NSLog shows:
Set count: 0

---

Looking deeper into the matter and already suggested by the above count, the NSSet object is actually passed, but looses it's record(s).

Is it not that an NSSet retains its objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `getSet` returns an actual `NSSet` and not a mutable subclass hiding under an `NSSet` “base pointer”? If it is mutable, it is possible for the set to be modified within the 0.5 second delay. Even if `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` retains the set, it does not prevent it from being modified.

Answer (score 1):

Does `myMethod` actually take an argument? It's important to note that method names and selectors in Objective-C actually include the colons that are present in the declaration; therefore, a method like this:

```
 - (void)myMethod:(NSSet *)set;
```

must be referenced with `@selector(myMethod:)`, including the trailing colon.

Comment: Yes it does. I updated the question to show the call, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After returning from the first message (or in part below the posted code snip), do you by accident alter the `NSSet` delivered by `[self getSet]`? If you remove objects from the set afterwards,`myMethod:` will not be able to access it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:myNSSetObject afterDelay:0.5];
```

instead (note the colon behind the message name).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:myNSSetObject afterDelay:0.5]
```

Assuming `myMethod:` is a method that takes an object?